# How to pass argument to Angularjs's router-ui without showing up in URL?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I have an AngularJS app that uses [ui-router](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router) to manage my app's states and URL routing.

Here is a sample state:

```
.state('my_state', {
    url: '/my_state/:arg1',
    templateUrl: 'http://www.example.com/html/my_file.html',
    controller: 'MyCtrl'
})
```

Here is it's controller:

```
app.controller('MyCtrl', function($stateParams) {
    console.log('arg1 = ', $stateParams.arg1)     
);
```

Here is how I send people to it from within another controller:

```
$state.go('my_state', {'arg1': 'hello'});
```

When the `$state.go` line above is executed, I get sent to this URL `/my_state/hello` and I see the following printed to the browser's debug window:

```
arg1 = hello
```

Now here is my question: Can I add another argument to this controller such that:

1. It is named `arg2`.
2. It is optional.
3. If provided, it can be accessed inside `MyCtrl`.
4. It does not show up in the URL.

If so, please show me how.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Route parameters in UI Router are optional by default.* For example you code (following) says that `arg1` is an *optional* parameter. So both `/my_state/:arg1` and `/my_state/` will work, but not `/my_state` (no trailing slash). It also reveals the `arg1` value in the URL.

```
.state('my_state', {
    url: '/my_state/:arg1',
    templateUrl: 'http://www.example.com/html/my_file.html',
    controller: 'MyCtrl'
})
```

**You Can add** another optional argument to this controller with your preferences :

```
.state('my_state', {
    url: '/my_state/:arg1',
    templateUrl: 'http://www.example.com/html/my_file.html',
    controller: 'MyCtrl',
    params: {
        arg2: { value: null }
    }
})
```

**To hide parameters** you have to define them in `params`.

**Note that** the `squash` property (inside `params`) configures *how a default parameter value is represented in the URL **when the current parameter value is the same as the default value***. If squash is not set, it uses the configured default squash policy.

[Working Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/7FasgTkoFCW8nNLWLTqw)

**Update**

Another [Working Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/ewTzDz9lKmd9xB16KlBh) which uses `$state.go('my_state', {'arg1': 'hello', 'arg2': 'world'});` inside controller.

**Note that** *there is no functional difference between `ui-sref` and `$state.go` for [Activating a state](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki#activating-a-state)*

Comment: This didn't work. Arg2 is exposed in the URL path. It shows up like this: `http://www.example.com/my_state/hello/world`. It seems like I might have to change how I'm directing the browser to `my_state`. Shouldn't I tell `$state.go()` to `POST` arg2 instead of putting in the URL which is what `GET` does?

Comment: @SaqibAli Oh sorry. I forgot to remove `arg2` from the `url`. This solves the problem. I also placed a working plunker at the end.

Comment: You used the following line in a template file to get to my_state: `<a ui-sref="my_state({ arg1: 'hello', arg2: 'world'})">`. Can you show me how I would do the same from inside another controller? When I do `$state.go('my_state', {'arg1': 'hello', 'arg2': 'world'});`, `$stateParams.arg2` is undefined inside `MyCtrl`.

Comment: @SaqibAli There is sth wrong with your code. I appended another plunker at the end of answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
.state('someState', {
            url: '/my_state?arg1',
            templateUrl: 'http://www.example.com/html/my_file.html', // I assume this is correct for the way you set it up.
            controller: 'MyCtrl',
            params: { // This is the part you'll add
                arg2: {
                    value: null, // you can set a default value
                    squash: true
                }
            }
})
```

This should do the trick for you! I've used it plenty of times! Very useful.

Comment: My url is `url: '/my_state/:arg1`. But you used `url: '/my_state?arg1',`
Can you use mine? If so, please edit you answer.

Comment: This solution doesn't work. I changed `$state.go('my_state', {'arg1': 'hello'});` to `$state.go('my_state', {'arg1': 'hello', 'arg2': 'world'});` And in the `MyCtrl` controller, I added the following line: `console.log('$stateParams = ', $stateParams);`. That console line printed `$stateParams = {#: null, arg1: "hello"}`. arg2 is nowhere to be seen!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
.state('my_state', {
    url: '/my_state',
    templateUrl: 'http://www.example.com/html/my_file.html',
    controller: 'MyCtrl',
    params: null
})
```

Comment: This omits arg1.

Answer (score 0):

```
Using Parameters without Specifying Them in State URLs
```

You still can specify what parameters to receive even though the parameters don't appear in the url. You need to add a new field params in the state and create links as specified in Using Parameters in Links

For example, you have the state.

```
.state('contacts', {
        url: "/contacts",
        params: {
            param1: null
        },
        templateUrl: 'contacts.html'
    })
```

The link you create is

```
<a ui-sref="contacts({param1: value1})">View Contacts</a>
```

Or you can pass them to `$state.go()` too.

```
$state.go('contacts', {param1: value1})
```